# Facebook Sharer Doesn't Get Thumbnail

Tags: fbml, xfbml, facebook-sharer, facebook-fbml

I tried `meta property="og:image"` , `meta property="og:image:security"`and `link rel="image_src"` but when i click link, sharer doesn't get thumbnail. It shows title, description and url. I tried to rescale the images to `90x90`, `200x200` and `500x500` but nothing happened. Here is the code:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="URL">
<meta property="og:title" content="TITLE">
<meta property="og:description" content="DESCRIPTION" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:image" content="IMAGE">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SITE NAME">

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=url" target="_blank">Share on FB!</a>
```

PS: I got https too and i also tried on it.

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be for a number of reasons, but without seeing your actual code (not blanked out with `IMAGE`, `SITE NAME` etc) I can only hazard a few guesses.

1. **Your site is hosted locally or password protected**

   It's sometimes a silly mistake people make, if you're developing this locally and you put in a locally hosted image as the `og:image` content then facebook wont be able to load the image correctly.
2. **Not a valid URL**

   Load the `og:image` URL and see if loads. If it doesn't, that's your problem.
3. **Your image is invalid. This is what facebooks [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) has to say on the image properties:**

   > > og:image - An image URL which should represent your object within the graph. The image must be at least 50px by 50px, although a minimum 200px by 200px is preferred and 1500px by 1500px is recommended for the best possible user experience. The image can have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1. We support PNG, JPEG and GIF formats. You may include multiple og:image tags to associate multiple images with your page. (Note: image sizes must be no more than 5MB in size.)
4. **Facebook has blocked your domain**

   Unlikely, but possible. See below regarding using the facebook debugger.

You are able to use [Facebooks debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) - just type your URL in and it will give you all the information you need. Including the `og:image` property.

If nothing is picked up, make sure you're including the tags correctly in your page, which you can see [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/).

**If** absolutely none of the above works, and you really can't get anything to work for you, you can include the URL directly in the share URL link - I've made an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dYfwK/) for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried all the things you said and example you wrote at jsfiddle worked! But one more thing i'd like to learn, can i get multiple images with this way? I tried to add "images[1]" but it didn't work.

Comment: That's a good point @BerkeSütçü, I tried [images][] and images[0] images[1] but it didn't work. Unfortunately this functionality isn't documented anywhere on facebook so I can't see if it's possible.

Comment: So i must make meta tags work to set multiple images then. Thanks for all helps anyway.

Comment: You can use multiple `og:image` meta elements to specify more than one image.

Comment: @CBroe i know that. I also asked that in this thread. I need alternative way to do that.