# Setting a facebook thumbnail for my site

Tags: html

I'm trying to set a facebook thumbnail to my site by the meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="example.jpg">
```

I have no idea why but it doesn't work.. you can try it by your self. my website address is: [www.spikes.co.il](http://www.spikes.co.il)

and more important the view-source:http://spikes.co.il/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Sharer Doesn't Get Thumbnail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981247/facebook-sharer-doesnt-get-thumbnail)

Comment: You have to give a full URL for the image, not a relative path.

Comment: @CBroe I gave my site address so you can see the source: <meta property="og:image" content="www.globalsport.se/image/cache/data/Spikskor/Nike%202012/Ja%20Fly/Zoom-Ja-Fly-2012-13-800x600.jpg">

Comment: That is not an absolute URL, that is a relative path pointing to something laying in a directory named `www.globalsport.se` underneath the current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `http://` before the address. Change it from this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="www.globalsport.se/image/cache/data/Spikskor/Nike%202012/Ja%20Fly/Zoom-Ja-Fly-2012-13-800x600.jpg">
```

to this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.globalsport.se/image/cache/data/Spikskor/Nike%202012/Ja%20Fly/Zoom-Ja-Fly-2012-13-800x600.jpg">
```

Comment: Thank you! I will mark your answer as correct as soon as possible.